# How to run multiple request in SOAP UI and Store all Response?

Tags: soapui

I am having some 100 Request in one folder.I wish to run all the request one by one and need to capture the response for all the request in SOAP UI.

Could someone help me on this with the details?

Comment: Are those 100 requests relatively stable or is the API you're wanting to test not fixed yet?

Comment: Actually,I will have some X Request in One Folder and need to run all the request and capture the response for those request.

Comment: Have you tried running SoapUI from command line with the -A or -a switch? http://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-from-command-line/functional-tests.html

Comment: As I understand you don't have the X requests (to different methods?) in a test case. Afaik you need to put all of them in a test case. Independently of putting them in one or X test cases you will need to write a groovy script that iterates over all those cases and extract their responses to a file.

If you want to send those X requests to the same method, but with different requests, I would suggest following Raos answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can create a test case with two steps:

- Groovy Script step
- SOAP Request step

Groovy Script step:

1. provide directory location as input to this step
2. read a file as text
3. set text as request for soap request step
4. run the soap request step
5. read the response and save the result
6. repeat till the file list lasts and exist (do not allow to the soap step one more time)

SOAP Request Step
this will initially have some request, and above groovy step overwrites each time it reads file.

So, you have to implement the groovy using above sudo steps.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE** based on the below comments, adding the groovy script.

```groovy
/**
* Closure definition requires inputs
* stepIndex : index of the request step where new content to be set
* contentToSet : the new request read from file
**/
def setRequest = { stepIndex, contentToSet ->
    def step = context.testCase.testStepList[stepIndex]
    step.testRequest.requestContent = contentToSet
}
//You may read a directory get the list of files and loop thru below steps for each file

//Read the request from file
def content = new File('/file/absolute/path').text

//Call above closure
//Assuming that Test Request step the second step, index becomes 1
setRequest(1, content)
```

Comment: I will try with the above steps:)

Comment: Hi Rao, I have tried to achive the your scenario and am not able to complete the script for the steps.          If you don't mind, could you share me the script for this?  Consider am having the Request in Input Folder(C:\Input) and wants to store the responses in the output folder (C:\Output).

Comment: Hi Rao, I couldn't find the method to achieve the step 3. Could you help me on the step 3 with some sample script?

Comment: Yes Rao. I have understood the logic and completed my implementation. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Glad to know that it helped.